# How to stop media player in new activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am a newbie to Android and have got stuck at **stopping media player within the same activity**.
I want to create an app that plays different music for different activities.
I am unable to stop the music once the first activity is created.
Even when I quit my app, the music is still playing.

Here is my code:

```
public class LayoutThreeActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_three);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.layout_three, menu);
    return true;


}


public void openNewActivity(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LayoutOneActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song2);
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to release the player OnPause or OnDestroy method.

```
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       if (mp!= null) mp.release();
   }
```

Comment: i have used the code but nothing happened, the problem still persists.

Comment: @user3290206 `MediaPlayer mp;` should be declared on the class level rather than an instance

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create an app that plays different music for different
>   activities.

Then Put this thing above your onCreate method & below class Name In each Activity you want to play MediaPlayer:

```
   MediaPlayer mp=null;
```

In your onCreate() method start your music & remove this code from openNewActivity() method:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song2);
mp.start();
```

> I am unable to stop the music once the first activity is created. Even
>   when I quit my app, the music is still playing.

Then put this in your each activity in which You have Start the MediaPlayer:

```
@Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            mp.stop();
        }
    @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            mp.stop();
        }
```